# We couldn't clone the repository. Try rerunning the pipeline Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, pipeline, runner

I'm trying to set my Bitbucket pipeline with runner. I can run my pipeline. I can build my project but repository couldnt clone when i add the runner option as ;

runs-on:

- self.hosted
- windows

The problem is only showing if i add runs-on syntax.
My runner is online and the labels are correct.
I can clone my repository by the way. Repository has no issue with that.
I tried to another project and its another branch.
I followed recommened yml draft.
I tried work with my runner long time ago. And same pipelines.yml was working.
I recreate my runner as well. The answer is the same.

This is my pipeline.yml running corrently before but now it is not working
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
pipelines:
branches:
Deploy_Test:
- step:
name: "IIS Website/Pool  Stop"
runs-on:
- self.hosted
- windows
script:
- Stop-IISSite -Name "test-wgt" -Confirm:$false

My runnig pipeline for building project;
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

pipelines:
default:
- step:
name: Build and Test
caches:
- dotnetcore
script:
- dotnet build TestSharedB1/TestSharedB1.csproj

Thanks for all.

- **ABP Framework version**: v6.0.2
- **UI Type**: Angular
- **Database System**: EF Core (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc..)
- **Tiered (for MVC) or Auth Server Separated (for Angular)**:  yes[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TbDv.png)

The problem is only showing if i add runs-on syntax.
My runner is online and the labels are correct.
I can clone my repository by the way. Repository has no issue with that.
I tried to another project and its another branch.
I followed recommened yml draft.
I tried work with my runner long time ago. And same pipelines.yml was working.
I recreate my runner as well. The answer is the same.